Cannot check index of a certain string in a PDF using Node
I am attempting to make a Node js program to read a bank statement PDF and detect the dates (Dates are on their own lines and have a '/' in the third position in each string).
This is my code so far:
import {PdfReader} from "pdfreader";
import { convertArrayToCSV } from "convert-array-to-csv";

new PdfReader().parseFileItems("600067301-2024-04-03.pdf",(err,item) => {
    if (err){
        console.warn("error: err"); 
    }
    else if (!item){
        console.warn("end of file");  
    }
    else if (item.text[2] === '/'){
        console.log('date found!!!'); 
    }
})

This is the error I'm getting:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2')
at file:///Users/Zayan/index.mjs:11:23
at PdfReader.parseFileItems (file:///Users/Zayan/node_modules/pdfreader/PdfReader.js:49:3)
The weird thing is that I am able to console.log (item.text[2] === '/') which does return True for the date lines, however it doesn't work for the else if statement.

I'm suspecting there is a problem with the if statement
If you can log the value of item.text[2] === '/' without the if statement and it's logging true then try to modify this if else statement and use Try/Catch block to handle errors gracefully
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

The error message implies that item exists, but item.text does not.
